# Remove chain of duplicate elements with HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to remove any duplicate or more occurrences of any **< br >** tags in my html document. This is what I've come up with so far (really stupid code):

```
HtmlNodeCollection elements = nodeCollection.ElementAt(0)
                             .SelectNodes("//br");

if (elements != null)
{
    foreach (HtmlNode element in elements)
    {
        if (element.Name == "br")
        {
             bool iterate = true;
             while(iterate == true)
             {
                 iterate = removeChainElements(element);
             }
         }
     }
}

private bool removeChainElements(HtmlNode element)
{
    if (element.NextSibling != null && element.NextSibling.Name == "br")
    {
        element.NextSibling.Remove();
    }
    if (element.NextSibling != null && element.NextSibling.Name == "br")
         return true;
    else
         return false;
    }
}
```

The code does find the **br** tags but it doesn't remove any elements at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you too complicated your solution, although the idea is seems to be correct, as I understand.

Suppose, it would be easier to find all the `<br />` nodes first, and just remove those, whose previous sibling is `<br />` node.

Let's start with the next example:

```
var html = @"<div>the first line<br /><br />the next one<br /></div>";
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
```

now find `<br />` nodes and remove the chain of duplicate elements:

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//br").ToArray();
foreach (var node in nodes)
    if (node.PreviousSibling != null && node.PreviousSibling.Name == "br")
        node.Remove();
```

and get the result of it:

```
var output = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

it is:

```
<div>the first line<br>the next one<br></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Solved it with a modified solution of this. Apparently the HTML Agility Pack interprets two following <br> nodes as one br node followed by an empty text node and then followed by a br node. Thus I had to check the previous node **two** steps back. So: **`element.PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.Name == "br"`** solved it with some null checks before it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do this `htmlsource = htmlSource.Replace("<br /><br />", <br />);`

or maybe something like this

```
    string html = "<br><br><br><br><br>";

    html = html.Replace("<br>", string.Empty);

    html = string.Format("{0}<br />", html);

    html = html.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
    html = html.Replace("\t", string.Empty);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I was unclear about what i wanted, but i need it to remove everything but one of the elements. So if there are 1000 br tags it should remove all of them but one.

Comment: That would work, but I believe that I need to use the HTML Agility Pack since I'm parsing a website and the HTML is malformed, so <br> might occur and also there might be alot of white space between the tags and so forth.

Comment: and then remove the whitespace and or tabs

Comment: I guess it would be possible to use that kind of method if the occurrences only happened in one place in the document. Since the added br tag is only appened to the end of the whole document. I could use regexp too but I believe the preferred way to this is by using a parser, like the HTML Agility Pack, atleast that's what I've been reading